# Convert timestamp from numerical to date in full using SQL and/or Python

Tags: sql

I'm trying to use an `SQL query/clause` to covert `numerical timestamp data` in a table i.e. `2016-07-31 19:54:22+00` into a written date i.e. `July 31, 2016`.

I only need the data, I don't want the time. Help with this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why not do this in Python?  And, "2016-07-31 19:54:22+00" is not "numeric.  Also, date functions are notoriously database specific, so you would have to specify the database.

Comment: "date functions are notoriously database specific, so you would have to specify the database" yes I assumed this. My database is "news", the database table I'm using is "log" and the timestamp column "time". I just didn't include that information in my original question because I was keeping it general to suit other peoples queries. I am aware I can do this in Python but I was hoping to contain it within a sql query. Any ideas?

Comment: . . relational databases go by names such as "Postgres", "MySQL", "SQL Server", "Sybase", "Oracle", "Teradata", "BigQuery", "Hive", "DB2"  (there are others) and if you stretch the definition "MS Access".

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Yes I should have stated "Postgres". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case it's any help to anyone I just did:
SELECT to_char(time, 'Month DD, YYYY') AS date

*'time' being the name of the timestamp column in my database table.